# How to map all calls to *.html in a springboot controller?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to serve dynamic html pages with Thymeleaf template and springboot api. This is the scenario that I want to achieve.

When someone makes the following request: **hostname/client** then the application would return a Json object on the other hand if someone makes this request: **hostname/client.html**, this request is catch  in a different controller so that I can manipulate the view that will be returned.

**Client Controller** 
 This class is working as expected, it is returning a Json Object

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    public ClientService clientServiceImp;

   @RequestMapping("/client")
    public Client get(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name){
        return clientServiceImp.getClient(name);
    }
}
```

**Home Controller**
 This class's method does not map calls to *.html

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value={"/*.html"},  produces="text/html")   
    public String getIndex(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

     // I will set here the thymeleaf fragment location based on the resource requested.
        return "index";
    }
```

*This is the error I am receiving after calling hostname/client.html
Whitelabel Error Page
*This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jan 25 16:04:56 BRST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation**

**Springboot basic configuration**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.serviceira"})
public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        }
}
```

It is important to point that I did not set any other configuration for the application. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to set up servlet mapping for `.html`. Are you using xml or java config

Answer (score 0):

The reason `ClientController` is working properly is because you marked it as a `@RestController`, you are telling Spring to write the response to the html page directly.

However, your `HomeController` is not finding the mapping because you have not set up the servlet mapping yet.

If you are in Java config:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");  // HERE YOU ARE SETTING THE .html mapping
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("your package name here");
        return context;
    }

}
```

If you are using XML, besides setting up your servelt, you need a mapping like this:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply mate. However it did not work I implemented as shown but it still not able to catch the request in the controller. I am using only java conf... I can call anything with the html extension and then the controller getIndex() works but if I call client.html it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

I solved the problem by adding different "produces" argument for for each controller's RequestMapping annotation, *besides to change the value from the getIndex from /*.html to *.html.*

**HomeController**

```
 @RequestMapping(value={"*.html"},  produces="text/html")
```

**ClientController**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/client" produces="application/json")
```

Now, every request that contains *.html is received and treated by the getIndex method from the HomeController class and the others are handled by its own controller. For example:

**request:**    GET: localhost/client
**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/client" produces="application/json")
        public Client get(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name){
            return clientServiceImp.getClient(name);
        }
```

**request:**    GET: localhost/client.html
**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value={"*.html"},  produces="text/html")   
        public String getIndex(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

         // I will set here the thymeleaf fragment location based on the resource requested.
            return "index";
        }
```